# Seeking a good model for extrapolation

Tags: estimation, extrapolation

I have two parallel data sets.

Set #1 is from the federal government, showing for instance, the following data for 2010

number of food processing firms in county for 2010: 74

total number of employees in all firms in this year: 3446

Meanwhile, it seems the federal government has left out some firms, and the county actually has good data on this year and shows a total of 249 firms.

It is a safe assumption that the data in this collection is a power law distribution.

What I am hoping to do is find a model that will let me extrapolate an estimate where for instance I can do the following

- fed employment total: 3446
- fed total firms: 74
- county total firms: 249
- estimated/extrapolated total employees based on extra firms: N

I've explored using bspline methods (for instance from scipy)

Any suggestions on a model or approach that can do this kind of estimation reasonably? Again, it is likely that the other 175 firms are all smaller/having less employees/fitting into a power law distribution. They were left out of federal data because they were "too small to track".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a statistical question. You are going to make a *guesstimate* based on the data. The results would completely depend on your assumptions and you don’t seem to have any relevant data to validate it. What you need to do is to go through domain literature, discuss it with domain experts, etc and use this information to make an educated guess. Based on such information, you would decide on some model, but there’s no good or bad answers, since it’s just a guess.